# How to Set Title Size with this Specific Pandas Plot Format

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Forgive me if this is not the newest question but after researching the site I am unable to identify a relevant example. I would like to set the title size directly in my Pandas Plot with the below code:

```
df['attribute'].value_counts().plot('bar', title='The title')
```

What property would I have to set in the "plot" method?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'attribute': list('aabbbcccd')})
ax = df['attribute'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='The title')
ax.title.set_size(20)
```

---

[image]

Comment: mhmhm there's no way to put that directly into the plot method?

Comment: Actually I am getting error: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'

Comment: What is your pandas and matplotlib versions?

Comment: I have Pandas 0.24.2 and Matplotlib 2.2.3 with Python 3.6

Comment: @Odisseo - Is possible upgrade? Tested in `pandas 0.25.0` and `matplotlib       : 3.1.0`